# how can a data from backend a text with a link becomes clickable in frontend?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs3

for example i have this `objects of array`:

```
const data = [
  { name: 'John', age: 25, 'body' : "this data has link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" },
  { name: 'Jane', age: 31, 'body' : "this data has link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" },
  { name: 'Bob', age: 18, 'body' : "this data has link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" }
];
```

how can i make it become a `link` when display it in `frontend`?

Comment: This is a very broad topic but in general, you'd need to parse the strings for URLs, transform them into `<a>` tags and use something like `v-html` to display them. But then you'd need to be wary of other, unwanted markup already in the strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood You correctly , please take a look at following snippet:

```js
const { reactive, computed } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const mydata = reactive([
      { name: 'John', age: 25, 'body' : "this data has link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" },
      { name: 'Jane', age: 31, 'body' : "this data has link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" },
      { name: 'Bob', age: 18, 'body' : "this data has link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" }
    ])
    const formatedData = computed(() => {
      const expression = / *https:.+/
      return mydata.map(d => {
        let link = d.body.match(expression)
        d.body = d.body.replace(expression, ` <a href="${link}">${link}</a>`)
        return d
      })
    })
    return { mydata, formatedData }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-for="(dat, i) in formatedData" :key="i">
    <p>{{ dat.name }} - <span>{{ dat.age }}</span></p>
    <div v-html="dat.body"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but the body doesn't contain link alone, it has text together with it. and the clickable is only the link.

Comment: @Mikael Tenshio hey mate, please check my answer again

Comment: can you somehow transform it to composition api mate.

Comment: sure, take a look again